# output a llst of vectors from a two column data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to convert a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2), code=c("a","b","c","a","b"))
```

to this output list where the name of each list contains the row id.

```
a_list <- list(
  Tr1 = c("a","b","c"),
  Tr2 = c("a","b")
)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

if not interested in names:

```
unstack(df, code~id)
$`1`
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$`2`
[1] "a" "b
```

or even:

```
 unstack(rev(df))
$`1`
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$`2`
[1] "a" "b"

with(df, split(code, id))
$`1`
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$`2`
[1] "a" "b"
```

if interested in names:

```
  unstack(transform(df, id=paste0('Tr', id)), code~id)
$Tr1
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$Tr2
[1] "a" "b"
```

or even:

```
with(df, split(code, paste0('Tr', id)))
$Tr1
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$Tr2
[1] "a" "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split`, i.e.

```
l1 <- split(df$code, df$id)
setNames(l1, paste0('Tr', seq_along(l1)))

$Tr1
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$Tr2
[1] "a" "b"
```